# How do I integrate Shipbook remote logging platform with Timber in android?

Tags: android, timber-android, shipbook

How do I integrate [Shipbook](https://shipbook.io) remote logging platform with [Timber](https://github.com/JakeWharton/timber) in android?

I've done the following code:

```
Timber.plant(new Timber.Tree() {

  @Override

  protected void log(int priority, @Nullable String tag, @NotNull String message, @Nullable Throwable t) {

    Log.message(tag, message, priority, t);

  }

});
```

The problem is that the Loglytics in Shipbook is seeing all logs as the same log and isn't differentiating between logs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell to Shipbook that Timber and your Timber Tree class are wrapper classes with `ShipBook.addWrapperClass`.

Just write the following code:

```
ShipBook.addWrapperClass(Timber.class.getName());

Timber.plant(new Timber.Tree() {

    {

      ShipBook.addWrapperClass(this.getClass().getName());

    }


    @Override

    protected void log(int priority, @Nullable String tag, @NotNull String message, @Nullable Throwable t) {

        Log.message(tag, message, priority, t);

    }

});
```

Good luck